# Showing git branches in termnial

Tags: git

I'm using ubuntu 16.04, and I'm trying to get my terminal to show the current git branch, that I'm on, without much success.

First, I went into my .bashrc file

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

then I posted in this code

```
parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

after I restarted the console, I still don't see the current branch. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
git branch | grep "^*"
```

Example:

```
$ git branch
  k410
  k411
  k412
  k413
  k416
  k416idle
  k416poll
  k416rc7-poll
  k418
  k418-jrw
  k418-rjw2
  k418-ufw2
  k418rc1test
* k419-rjw
  k45
  k46
  master
  ufw-test
```

And now:

```
$ git branch | grep "^*"
* k419-rjw
```